# What is the difference in meaning between "if I do something" and "if I am going to do something"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, progressive-aspect

What is the difference in meaning between *if I do something* and *if I am going to do something*? For example:

> **If I take** a cab, I will be just in time.
>
> **If I am going to take** a cab, I will be just in time.
>
> **If I pass** the exams, I will be accepted to the college.
>
> **If I am going to pass** the exams, I will be accepted to the college.

Comment: As a learner,  I would understand the progressive ones as if you are talking about a momentary situation or at the moment. I don't know why. However, the rest give me a sense of generality.

Comment: Actually that is not progressive, but rather "be going to" for future events.

Comment: I know, that was just a way that  I used to refer to those two sentences. Still it has the progressive aspect structure though!

Comment: "If I climb Mount Everest,  I will take a week off."  I can not take a week off until after I climb Mount Everst.  "If I am going to climb Mount Everest, I will take a week off."  If I INTEND to climb Mount Everest some time in the future, I can take the week off now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the phrase "If I am going to X" is best suited as a predecessor to some detail about the carrying out of X, rather than an effect of carrying out X. See these examples:

> If I am going to take a cab, the cab better arrive on time.
>
> If I am going to pass the exams, I am going to need to hit the books soon.

When speaking of an effect of carrying out X, as you did in your examples, "If I X" seems to be the phrase of choice.